# Issue on pricing bond using RQuantLib

Tags: bond, pricing, rquantlib

trying to pricing a simple bond using RQuantLib, but cannot get the right values. 
For example, consider a bond with 2% annual coupon rate and flat interest rate of 3%, a 5 year maturity, and \$100 face value. I can get the $\textrm{NPV} = 95.42029$ by simple calculation:

$$2/(1+0.03) + 2/(1+0.03)^2 + 2/(1+0.03)^3 + 2/(1+0.03)^4 + 102/(1+0.03)^5.$$

However, when I use RQuantLib:

```
bond <- list(settlementDays=1,
               issueDate=as.Date("2010-02-16"),
               faceAmount=100,
               accrualDayCounter='ActualActual.Bond',
               paymentConvention='Unadjusted')
  schedule <- list(effectiveDate=as.Date("2010-02-16"),
                   maturityDate=as.Date("2015-02-16"),
                   period='Annual',
                   calendar='UnitedStates/GovernmentBond',
                   businessDayConvention='Unadjusted',
                   terminationDateConvention='Unadjusted',
                   dateGeneration='Backward',
                   endOfMonth=0)
  calc=list(dayCounter='ActualActual.Bond',
            compounding='Compounded',
            freq='Annual',
            durationType='Modified')
  coupon.rate <- c(0.02)
  params <- list(tradeDate=as.Date('2010-02-16'),
                 settleDate=as.Date('2010-02-17'),
                 dt=.25,
                 interpWhat="discount",
                 interpHow="loglinear")
  setEvaluationDate(as.Date("2010-02-16"))
  discountCurve.flat <- DiscountCurve(params, list(flat=0.03))
  FixedRateBond(bond,
                coupon.rate,
                schedule,
                calc,
                discountCurve=discountCurve.flat)
```

I got the following results:

```
Concise summary of valuation for FixedRateBond 
 Net present value :  95.22618 
       clean price :  95.221 
       dirty price :  95.226 
    accrued coupon :  0.0055556 
             yield :  0.030454 
          duration :  4.6575 
   settlement date :  2010-02-17 
        cash flows : 
       Date Amount
 2011-02-16      2
 2012-02-16      2
 2013-02-16      2
 2014-02-16      2
 2015-02-16      2
 2015-02-16    100
```

Another strange thing happens when I change the accrualDayCounter = Actual365NoLeap. I should expect the accrued coupon = 2/365 = 0.005479 (because only 1-day accrual). However, RQuantLib still gives 0.0055556 (=2/360). It seems changing the daycounter does not have any effect. What am I doing wrong here? Thank you for your help.